# Add identifier of first created record to select statement with group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, clickhouse

I have the following payments table

```
┌─name───────────────────────────┬─type────────────────────────────┐
│ payment_id                     │ UInt64                          │
│ factory                        │ String                          │
│ user_id                        │ UInt64                          │
│ amount_cents                   │ Int64                           │
│ action                         │ String                          │
│ success                        │ UInt8                           │
│ country                        │ FixedString(2)                  │
│ created_at                     │ DateTime                        │
│ finished_at                    │ Nullable(DateTime)              │
└────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

With sample data

```
┌─factory───┬─────────finished_at─┬─payment_id─┬─country─┬─action──┬─amount_cents─┬─user_id───┬
│ 0_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:01 │          1 │ BY      │ payment │            1 │         1 │ 
│ 0_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:02 │          2 │ BY      │ payment │            1 │         1 │ 
│ 1_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:02 │          2 │ PL      │ win     │            4 │         1 │ 
│ 1_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:03 │          3 │ PL      │ win     │            7 │         1 │ 
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:01 │          4 │ PL      │ win     │            7 │         1 │ 
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:02 │          1 │ PL      │ payment │            7 │         1 │ 
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:03 │          2 │ PL      │ win     │            7 │         1 │ 
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:04 │          3 │ GR      │ win     │            2 │         1 │ 
└───────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

This is an example of what I have right now with

```
SELECT
       factory,
        user_id,
        payment_id,
        action,
        created_at
    FROM payments_all
    WHERE (payments_all.action = 'payment') AND (payments_all.factory IN ('0_factory', '1_factory', '2_factory')) AND isNotNull(payments_all.created_at)
    GROUP BY
        factory,
        user_id,
        payment_id,
        action
    HAVING (min(created_at) >= toDate('2019-01-01 00:00:00')) AND (min(created_at) < toDate('2021-10-01 00:00:00'))
    ORDER BY user_id

┌─factory───┬─user_id─┬─payment_id─┬─action──┬──────────created_at─┐
│ 1_factory │       1 │          1 │ payment │ 2021-02-04 09:00:00 │
│ 0_factory │       1 │          1 │ payment │ 2021-01-17 00:00:01 │
│ 0_factory │       1 │          2 │ payment │ 2021-01-17 00:00:06 │
└───────────┴─────────┴────────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

I need to add new column `first_payment`

`first_payment` takes value 1 if action is payment && it is first payment for a user. Otherwise it takes value 0.

the `first_payment` should be checked for all period
So expected result is:

```
┌─factory───┬─────────finished_at─┬─payment_id─┬─country─┬─action──┬─amount_cents─┬─user_id───┬first_payment─┐
│ 0_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:01 │          1 │ BY      │ deposit │            1 │         1 │           1  │
│ 0_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:02 │          2 │ BY      │ deposit │            1 │         1 │           0  │ 
│ 1_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:02 │          2 │ PL      │ win     │            4 │         1 │           0  │
│ 1_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:03 │          3 │ PL      │ win     │            7 │         1 │           0  │
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:01 │          4 │ PL      │ win     │            7 │         1 │           0  │
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:02 │          1 │ PL      │ deposit │            7 │         1 │           1  │
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:03 │          2 │ PL      │ win     │            7 │         1 │           0  │
│ 2_factory │ 2021-01-18 00:00:04 │          3 │ GR      │ win     │            2 │         1 │           0  │
└───────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Please tag database you need the solution for

Comment: it's CH, but it's fully compatible with MySQL

Comment: Which version of MySQL though?  MySQL8 or MariaDB, for example, have functionality MySQL5.7 does not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find much about ClickHouse, but it doesn't appear to support Windowed Functions.

Your example output also seems to be exactly the same as your sample table, plus one additional column, so I'm not sure what you `GROUP BY` was meant to achieve.

So, I'd use a `LEFT JOIN` on to a sub-query.

```
SELECT
  payments_all.*,
  CASE WHEN user_summary.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_payment
FROM
  payments_all
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    factory,
    MIN(created_at)  AS first_created_at
  FROM
    payments_all
  WHERE
    action = 'payment'
  GROUP BY
    user_id,
    factory
)
  AS user_summary
    ON  payments_all.user_id    = user_summary.user_id
    ON  payments_all.factory    = user_summary.factory
    AND payments_all.created_at = user_summary.first_created_at
WHERE
     (payments_all.factory    IN ('0_factory', '1_factory', '2_factory'))
 AND (payments_all.created_at >= toDate('2019-01-01 00:00:00'))
 AND (payments_all.created_at <  toDate('2021-10-01 00:00:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see for first payment the `payment_id` is always 1. So, I think you can use `CASE WHEN payment_id=1 Then 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_payment`. Please check query below =>

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
       factory,
        user_id,
        payment_id,
        action,
        created_at
    FROM payments_all
    WHERE (payments_all.action = 'payment') AND (payments_all.factory IN ('0_factory', '1_factory', '2_factory')) AND isNotNull(payments_all.created_at)
    GROUP BY
        factory,
        user_id,
        payment_id,
        action
    HAVING (min(created_at) >= toDate('2019-01-01 00:00:00')) AND (min(created_at) < toDate('2021-10-01 00:00:00'))
) T1  

SELECT *,CASE WHEN payment_id=1 Then 1
         ELSE 0 END AS first_payment 
FROM CTE  
ORDER BY T1.user_id
```

**NOTE:** Query is written in SQL Server. Please check and let me know.

Comment: but if there are 100 factories with their payments and users? There will be n_payment_id for each factory

Comment: Ok  then please provide full table schema and some sample data. If you can update the question then I can try it. :)

Comment: added schema and data sample